# how to know if the url is crawled by robots or clicked by user?

Tags: php, web-crawler, apache2

Daily I am getting same error from same IP at different time intervals.
Here are details,

```
<site_name> <same_site_name's_IP> - - [13/May/2012:16:27:30 +0100] "POST /forum/updateuserpassword.php HTTP/1.1" 500 237 "http://localhost/mgh/auth" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.9) Gecko/20061206 Firefox/1.5.0.9" mod_deflate: In:- Out:-:-pct.
```

some times it gets accepted showing 200 25 instead of 500 237 ....

What may be the issue?

Comment: Just from webserver logs there's no reliable way to tell.

Comment: The presence of a User Agent string suggests that it's not any reputable robot.  It's either a legit user or a robot that wants to mask its identity.

Comment: Almost certainly a bot/script. No one uses Firefox 1.5 anymore. You can also look at what it does before that request, for example, if it does not request the page/form before doing the POST request then it looks even more like a bot. Also if it does do the initial GET request, look at the time difference. Humans can't view a page then submit a form within the same second.

Comment: Look at the PHP error logs. You have enabled them, right?